# Eclipse: to src/ or not to src/

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two projects I created in Eclipse, one of which creates new classes in a src/ subdirectory, while the other creates them in the project root directory. (New classes are being created with Eclipse's File->New->Class menu item.)

What did I configure in these projects that makes them act differently?

How can I fix the project without a src/ sub-directory so it has one?

Comment: What's stopping you to create a directory named src and further packagaes under it. Once created, move the files under it.

Comment: When I choose File->New->Class from the menu, it puts them in the root directory instead of within src/

Comment: I can manually move it on the file system, and even edit the project config files to "make" it work, or even create a new project that works correctly, but I honestly have no idea why it decided it did not need a src directory in one case, and I cannot find any settings in Eclipse that would control this. I need to use Eclipse due to external requirements, but am not familiar with it. I want to make sure this doesn't happen again, so I need to understand how it happened in this case.

Comment: @BalwinderSingh I removed Senior, since I obviously don't deserve it

Comment: That wasn't my intention buddy. Have a look at my answer about the possible cause and how you can fix it. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Java project's **Build Path** property page. The **Source** tab indicates the root(s) of the source packages, and setting the project root itself as a `Source Folder` is perfectly valid. The wizard is just picking the first/default `Source Folder`.

Comment: Thanks, I see that now that you direct me to it. Note that it can NOT be edited to be the root directory of the project, but I did find an option in the new project wizard that says to use the project root instead of source and class folders, so that must have accidentally been selected when the project was created. Note further that it is not easy to fix from within Eclipse when it happens.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the java project, eclipse asks whether you wish to

- Use project folder as root for sources and class files
- Create separate source folders for sources and class files

Perhaps you selected the 1st option in one project and other in the next project.
[image]

If by mistake, you have configured the root folder as your source folder; then you can change it. Just right click on project --> **Build Path** --> **Configure Build Path**.

Select the **source** tab and update the source folder.

Hope this helps